# Be able to call a function from an enum? c#

Tags: c#, function, enums, callback, procedure

Basically, I wish to have an enum, where each constant is referencing a function *(more of an procedure however since it doesn't return anything)* .

```
enum Example {first_function, second_function, third_function};

void first_function (){
}
... you get the hang of it
```

Is there a method where I can call such function from an enum?

Thank you in advance and sorry, I just started learning today ;)

Comment: An enum's underlying type [_can be any integral type except char_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum). A function is not an integral type so you can't do that.

Comment: What is a use-case for that? Sounds a bit like XY problem. If this is really needed, I would go with  `Dictionary<Example, Action>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary with keys the enum values and values the functions you want to call. The only restriction on this approach is the fact that all the methods you want to call should have the same signature.

If the enum is the following:

```
enum Example { FirstFunction, SecondFunction, ThirdFunction }
```

and the methods don't get any parameters and they return nothing (void), you could try something like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Example, Action>
{
    { Example.FirstFunction, FirstFunction },
    { Example.SecondFunction, SecondFunction },
    { Example.ThirdFunction, ThirdFunction }
};
```

Then you could find the method for an enum value and call it as below:

```
dictionary[Example.FirstFunction]();
```

Apparently you methods can return any type you want and get as many arguments as you want. However, they must have all the same signature (return type and parameters).

Comment: That does seem to fix my problem, Thank you very much. I forgot about dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `enum` to designate a function, but if all your functions have identical signature, then you could make a `Dictionary` from your `enum` to an `Action<...>` with the corresponding parameters:

```
void Function1(int val) {
    ...
}
void Function2(int val) {
    ...
}
void Function3(int val) {
    ...
}

static readonly IDictionary<MyEnumType,Action<int>> MyEnumToAction = new Dictionary<MyEnumType,Action<int>> {
    [first_function] = Function1,
    [second_function] = Function2,
    [thrird_function] = Function3
};
```

You can now call it like this:

```
MyEnumToAction[myEnumValue](myIntArgument);
```

Comment: Thank you, that did seem to help me fix my problem. As I told Christos, I basically forgot about dictionaires